# How does C++ choose which operator overload to use?

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I'm writing a set of classes for custom serialization and deserialization. I figured I would use the << and >> operators since they convey that meaning generally. Let's start with a class for handling writing to a generic stream.

```
class Writer
{
public:
  virtual void writeBytes(const void* p, size_t n) = 0;
  template <typename T> void write(const T& v)
  {
    writeBytes(&v, sizeof(v));
  }
  template <typename T> Writer& operator<<(const T& v)
  {
    write(v);
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Then there's an interface for something that's serializable, i.e. that provides it's own method for serialization.

```
class Serializable
{
public:
  virtual Writer& serialize(Writer& writer) const = 0;
};

Writer& operator<<(Writer& writer, const Serializable& s)
{
  s.serialize(writer);
  return writer;
}
```

Finally, I wrote an example of how to use it: a serializable buffer.

```
class SerializableBuffer : public Serializable
{
public:
  SerializableBuffer() : data_(NULL), length_(0) { }
  SerializableBuffer(void* data, size_t length) : data_(data), length_(length) { }
  virtual Writer& serialize(Writer& writer) const
  {
    writer.writeBytes(data_, length_);
    return writer;
  }
private:
  void* data_;
  size_t length_;
};
```

So here's the interesting part. Obviously, if I use method calls, it does exactly what it's supposed to. But using the << operator is showing some quirks. My first attempt is to do the following:

```
  unsigned char input[] = { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFD, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xFA, 0x12, 0x34 };
  SerializableBuffer sb(input, sizeof(input));

  unsigned char d[8]; 
  BufferWriter writer(buffer(d));

  writer << sb;
```

This fails, because the output buffer isn't big enough. If I add a printf, it turns out that it's calling the template in the Writer class! Here's the weirder part, the following works.

```
  unsigned char input[] = { 0xFF, 0xFE, 0xFD, 0xFC, 0xFB, 0xFA, 0x12, 0x34 };
  SerializableBuffer sb(buffer(input));

  unsigned char d[8]; 
  BufferWriter writer(buffer(d));

  writer << (Serializable&)sb;
```

I'm guessing the templating engine is winning over a descendent? Can anyone explain what's going on here and why?

Comment: You have undefined behaviour in a few places because you have functions with a return type whose implementations don't return anything. You should fix that first.

Comment: Good catch. This is copy and paste from a much larger set of code, so I'm trying to pare it down for clarity.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. The problem is that the template in Writer will generate an operator specific to any class if it doesn't already exist. As a result the SerializableBuffer gets an operator generated for it. That's not very helpful. First: can anyone confirm that? Second: any idea how to make this work correctly?

Comment: "templating engine is winning over a descendent?"  Yes, that is one of the C++ language rules I hate.  Pass a derived class object to a function for which the available choices are a template (can be anything) or a base class, and the compiler will choose template rather than implied static cast to base class.

Comment: I came exactly to the same point when you wrote your remark. A last try you could give is to write a specialization for << (non template) accepting a SerializableBuffer and check that it 's more prioritary thatn the template. It's not surprising for me

Comment: My template meta-programming skills aren't this good, but many who answer here would know how to:  Write a template specialization that will only fit objects derived from Serializable.  That is then more specific than the main template definition, but can replace the non template definition.

Comment: Check out the [Overload resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) page on cppreference and [STL's lecture](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-Cpp-3-of-n) on channel9.

Answer (score 2):

Its pretty simple -- its just following the overload resolution rules.  You have two overloaded `operator <<` that can possibly match when the first argument is a `Writer &` or a subclass:

```
template <typename T> Writer& Writer::operator<<(const T& v);
Writer& operator<<(Writer& writer, const Serializable& s);
```

When the second argument is a `SerializableBuffer`, the first can match exactly, while the second can match with a conversion.  Since matching exactly is better, the first matches.

When the second argument is a `Serializable`, both match exactly, so the second is better as it is not a template.

If you want to make the template not match when the argument is a subclass of `Serializable`, you can use `enable_if`:

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Serializable, T>::value, Writer &>::type
operator<<(const T &v)
```

which will cause the template to not be instantiatable for any subclass of `Serializable`.

Comment: Is it possible to restrict the template so it doesn't get in the way of Serializable classes?

Comment: Maybe one could redefine `Writer::operator<<(const T& v)` to not be used when T is derived from Serializable (as you just requested), but that would probably be harder and definitely be uglier than the alternative (also beyong **my** skill) to replace `operator<<(Writer& writer, const Serializable& s)` with a template function `operator<<(Writer& writer, const T_S& s)` that would be used for all and only T_S derived from Serializable.  I would use that pattern a LOT if I knew it.